# Ask the user if they want to repeat the same task again

Tags: python

If the user gets to the end of the program I want them to be prompted with a question asking if they wants to try again. If they answer yes I want to rerun the program.

```
import random
print("The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values") 
print("that add up to a displayed target value.\n") 
print("Enter coins values as 1-penny, 5-nickel, 10-dime,and 25-quarter.") 
print("Hit return after the last entered coin value.")
print("--------------------") 
total = 0 
final_coin = random.randint(1, 99)
print("Enter coins that add up to", final_coin, "cents, on per line") 
user_input = int(input("Enter first coin: "))
total = total + user_input

if user_input != 1 and user_input!=5 and user_input!=10 and user_input!=25:
   print("invalid input")

while total != final_coin:
    user_input = int(input("Enter next coin: "))
    total = total + user_input

if total > final_coin:
    print("Sorry - total amount exceeds", (final_coin)) 

if total < final_coin:
    print("Sorry - you only entered",(total))

if total== final_coin: 
    print("correct")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enclose your entire program in another while loop that asks the user if they want to try again.

```
while True:
  # your entire program goes here

  try_again = int(input("Press 1 to try again, 0 to exit. "))
  if try_again == 0:
      break # break out of the outer while loop
```

Comment: can you not check directly in the while statement instead of an if statement. you can write `while try_again != 0` and then the entire code. as the last statement in the while, you can do `try_again = int(input(....))`

Answer (score 2):

This is an incremental improvement on the accepted answer:

Used as is, any invalid input from the user (such as an empty str, or the letter "g" or some such) will cause an exception at the point where the int() function is called.

A simple solution to such a problem is to use a try/except- try to perform a task/ code and if it works- great, but otherwise (except here is like an else:) do this other thing.

Of the three approaches one might try, I think the first one below is the easiest and will not crash your program.

#### Option 1: Just use the string value entered with one option to go again

```
while True:
    # your entire program goes here
    
    try_again = input("Press 1 to try again, any other key to exit. ")
    if try_again != "1":
        break # break out of the outer while loop
```

#### Option 2: if using int(), safeguard against bad user input

```
while True:
    # your entire program goes here

    try_again = input("Press 1 to try again, 0 to exit. ")
    try:
        try_again = int(try_again)  # non-numeric input from user could otherwise crash at this point
        if try_again == 0:
            break # break out of this while loop
    except:
        print("Non number entered")
```

#### Option 3: Loop until the user enters one of two valid options

```
while True:
    # your entire program goes here
    
    try_again = ""
    # Loop until users opts to go again or quit
    while (try_again != "1") or (try_again != "0"):
        try_again = input("Press 1 to try again, 0 to exit. ")
        if try_again in ["1", "0"]:
            continue  # a valid entry found
        else:
            print("Invalid input- Press 1 to try again, 0 to exit.")
    # at this point, try_again must be "0" or "1"
    if try_again == "0":
        break
```